# How to control Display Order in Custom Site Actions

Tags: custom-actions

There is a way to control the display order for custom actions added to Site Action menu? Always, new added custom actions are added to the end of the OOTB list.

Comment: I too have the same problem...Its always showing up in the end

Answer (score 2):

Check for the sequence number...

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't works.

Comment: hi, every element will have a sequence number. so can you try with a higher number and check it...

Comment: Sequence number has no effect. I tried lower and higher values with no effect. New item always appear at the end of the menu, that is after Settings item.